# Calculated columns in Access 2003 have null value when inserting into new table

Tags: ms-access, cobol

I have a make table query where some of the columns are calculated.  An example of how one of those columns looks is as follows:

```
SQFTCost: (([SUPPLY_MASTER]![LAST_COST]+[SUPPLY_MASTER]![FREIGHT_COST])/[SUPPLY_MASTER]![SQFT_PER_CTN])
```

In this case, LAST_COST is a decimal with a precision of 9 and a scale of 3.  FREIGHT_COST is is a decimal with a precision of 8 and a scale of 3, and SQFT_PER_CTN is a decimal with a precision of 7 and a scale of 3.

Whenever I run the make table query, that column and all the others like it are filled with nulls. I know that they are actually null, because I tested that in a routine that I wrote.

[image: table results]

However, if I change the query to a SELECT query, all is well.  The values are correct.

[image: table results]

Does anyone have any idea what can be done to fix this?  I am using Access 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across the correct answer to this issue.  It is the result of a sometimes flaky ODBC driver that we are using here.  Our data rests in COBOL files that are in the [Vision file format](http://www.acucorp.com/support/public/release_overviews/v6.0/60_info4.htm).  The trouble is coming from using fields that are defined in the [xfds](http://www.infotraxsys.com/dev/acudocs50/comprun/gt100227.htm) as [REDEFINES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee267452%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) of other fields in the file.  Using the original field fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just a few suggestions:

1. Try adding a cLng() or something equivalent in front of your expressions, to force a well defined data type
2. I avoid Make Table queries, preferring Append queries. Just make an "template" table properly set up, and use a copy with Append queries. It's the only way to have a clean design.

Comment: One thing that forcing a type did was bring to light a different issue and essentially the real one. The values are all null until Access displays them in this instance. I wonder if this is because a couple of these tables are linked ODBC tables. Generally, I will not use make tables when I do not need them.  Training the users around here to use template tables, delete queries and appends is a different story.

Comment: @ Buggabill: make table uses the first rows to decide the data types. That can be very bad. Just more ideas to solve your mystery: could you try setting your data sources as snapshots or similar ? Or eventually include a few NZ() in your formula ?

Comment: I figured it out.  That things that you suggested helped narrow things down.  I have posted the answer to the question. Thanks for the help. :-)

Comment: +1 for avoiding MakeTable queries. They should almost never be deployed in a production app.

Comment: If I were deploying a production app, I would totally agree.  These are queries for a user to use in gathering some information in their daily work. I actually did not write them, but have to provide support when they do break.  The things that I do in my daily work avoids make table queries when possible.